# Procurar um elemento na lista

Tags: python, array, algoritmo-de-busca

> Faça um programa que gerencie o resultado do vestibular. Para sua felicidade, só existe um curso e o curso tem 10 vagas. O programa deve manter a lista dos 10 classificados. O programa também mantém, em outra lista (de 20 posições), a lista de espera, que contém os
>   candidatos aprovados, mas excedentes ao número de vagas (caso algum candidato classificado
>   desista, será chamado um da lista de espera). A lista de espera pode ter até 20 candidatos.
>
> O programa deve solicitar o número do candidato e dizer:
>
> (a) se ele foi classificado, ou
>
> (b) se ele está na lista de espera,
>   neste caso, indicar em que lugar da fila de espera ele está, ou
>
> (c) se
>   ele não foi aprovado.

Exemplo. Sejam os classificados:
20 32 01 14 99 34 21 02 15 07

Seja a lista de espera (valor -1 significa que não há candidato):
08 04 10 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1

Exemplos de consultas:
Entrada / Saída
01 “classificado”
04 “número 2 na lista de espera
97 “não aprovado”

O que eu consegui fazer:

```
numeroCandidato = int(input("Entre com o numero do candidato: "))
classificados = [20,32,1,14,99,34,21,2,15,7]
listaDeEspera = [8, 4, 10]
if numeroCandidato not in classificados:
print("nao aprovado")
```

Comment: Você pode [edit] sua pergunta e adicionar o código de pelo menos uma das suas tentativas. Assim ficará mais fácil para te orientarmos, sabendo onde você está errando. E esse enunciado está bem confuso de entender. Você o colocou por completo ou omitiu algumas partes? Que informação será a entrada? A nota do candidato? Qual será a condição para definir se o mesmo foi classificado?

Comment: Bom dia! Então, tentei fazer o exercício mas não fiz quase nada... Agora sobre a interpretação: A entrada será o número do candidato, se o número que você entrou estiver na lista de classificados, irá aparecer uma mensagem falando que foi classificado. Se estiver na lista de espera, aparecerá uma mensagem falando a posição do candidato na lista de espera, e se o número não estiver em nenhuma das listas, aparecerá que ele não foi classificado. Teoricamente é assim a funcionalidade.

Comment: Se você fez **quase** nada, você deve ter feito algo. Comece postando esse algo, pelo menos para sabermos se você começou no caminho certo.

Comment: Postei até onde consegui, não consigo sair dali

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você já chegou bem perto da solução final. Para verificar se o candidato foi aprovado, basta verificar se o seu número consta na lista de classificados:

```
if numeroCandidato in classificados:
    print("Aprovado")
```

Para verificar se o candidato está na lista de espera, basta verificar se seu número consta na lista de espera:

```
elif numeroCandidato in listaDeEspera:
    print("Lista de espera")
```

Porém, pede-se também para informar em qual posição da lista de espera o candidato se encontra. Para tal, podemos utilizar o método `index` do objeto `listaDeEspera` para obter a posição do candidato. Vale lembrar que como os índices de uma lista em Python começam em 0, precisaremos incrementar o valor em um, para que se o candidato estiver na posição 0 da lista, apareca posição 1:

```
elif numeroCandidato in listaDeEspera:
    posicao = listaDeEspera.index(numeroCandidato) + 1
    print("Número %d na lista de espera." % posicao)
```

Finalmente, se nenhuma das condições acima for satisfeita, deve aparecer que o candidato não foi aprovado:

```
else:
    print("Não aprovado")
```

O código final, então, ficaria:

```
numeroCandidato = int(input("Entre com o numero do candidato: "))

classificados = [20,32,1,14,99,34,21,2,15,7]
listaDeEspera = [8, 4, 10, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1]

if numeroCandidato in classificados:
    print("Aprovado!")
elif numeroCandidato in listaDeEspera:
    posicao = listaDeEspera.index(numeroCandidato) + 1
    print("Número %d na lista de espera." % posicao)
else:
    print("Não aprovado.")
```

Comment: Então Anderson, copiei o código que você criou e deu um erro quando eu digito algum número que está na lista de espera. Segue o print: http://imgur.com/a/7O9Y2

Comment: Qual será o problema nesse caso? E já aproveitando a pergunta, pra não se estender muito por coisas simples. O professor nos disse para fazer esse exercício usando o "For", tentei fazer e não consegui. Como eu faria usando o "For"? Obrigado desde já!!

Comment: O problema foi na versão do Python, que ainda não existe a implementação do `format`. Irei alterar a resposta. Quanto ao `for`, não vejo como utilizá-lo nesta solução de maneira eficiente.

Comment: Tá certo, estou aguardando. Também não consigo utilizar o "For" nesse programa, por isso me confundi todo.

Comment: @Pigot acredito que agora funcionará. Eu realmente não vejo como utilizar `for` nesta solução.

Comment: Funcionou muito bem. Muito obrigado pela atenção cara, grato mesmo! Sou novo aqui no site, tem alguma forma de agradecer? Tipo aumentando reputação e tal? Valeu.

Comment: No lado esquerdo da resposta, há como você votar positivamente, indicando que a resposta foi útil e um pouco mais abaixo um ícone `v` para você indicar que a resposta resolveu o problema. Pode ler mais sobre [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).